# cmd new window store output

Tags: batch-file, cmd, lua, out

I want to open a new command prompt, run an program and save the output (which is right now displayed in the command prompt) in a logfile.

I used this command so far:

`cmd /c start "window title" "C:\Program Files\app.exe"`

normally I can use

`"C:\Program Files\app.exe" >out.txt`

to save what is written on the command prompt in a file. 
With the need, that the programm is executed in another window, I'm struggling to set the output correctly.

Why do I need the extra window?

--> The program will be called several times. I need a license for that, I'm limited there. If the program is called in the same window, after 3 three times an error occurrs, telling me, that I use to many license at the same time.

With extra opening and closing windows this "license problem" is solved. 
But the I cannot find the solution for the output then. 
Lua is tagged, since this command is embedded in Lua's `os.execute()`

Comment: Your question is unclear, you've already shown us the you know how to set the output to a file, so why are you struggling to set it?

Comment: Why do you use command `start`? `cmd /C` starts already a command process required for redirection of a standard console output into a file. The command `start` starts one more command process. So I don't see any reason for using command `start`. A shortcut (*.lnk) with the command `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe /C window title& "%ProgramFiles%\app.exe" >"%UserProfile%\Desktop\out.txt"` does exactly the same without starting a second command process from within already started command process.

Comment: It looks like you are searching for a solution to workaround limitation because of using a licensed application more often than granted by the bought license. You should purchase more licenses if you need more than working around the limitation caused by having not enough licenses.

Comment: IMHO, there is nothing wrong with working within the limitations of your license agreement.  There is something wrong with attempting to actually circumvent the enforcement of said license agreement.

Comment: @Compo :
I struggled because of the, for me rather new, syntax and qouting rules.

Comment: @ Mofi 
You asked: Why using `start`. 
Then you explained, what `start` does.
Well, it seems like I need one more command process. Or clearer: I need the old process to close. I work sequential on files. With limited licenses. If the old process isn't closed, I can't start a new computation. Presuming that I want to work around license limitation, isn't too nice. 
Sorry, if it wasn't clear at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows command line has wicked rules about quoting :-)
This code works as you need:

```
os.execute([["start "window title" cmd /C ""C:\Program Files\app.exe" > "C:\my logs\log.txt"""]])
```

Comment: Thanks. You understood the problem and found a solution. 
Short addition: How can I label the window with the current path. 
So instead of `"window title"` I need `"current path\variable"`.
Where `variable` is Lua variable (string type).

Comment: Just concatenate the strings: `os.execute([["start "]]..var..[[" cmd ...]])`

Answer (score 1):

You should examine `start /?` for the full syntax of the command.  You need the following elements:

- the `start` command
- `"window title"` (can be `""` if you don't wish to specify)
- `/d "working directory"`
- `"command name"`
- `"command arguments"`

... where each token after `start` is quoted.  Example:

```
start "" /d "C:\Program Files\appdir" "app.exe" ">%userprofile%\Desktop\out.txt"
```

Use the `start` command's expected argument structure to pass the output redirection as an argument.  Pass it quoted so the cmd interpreter knows you want the output of `app.exe` redirected, as opposed to the output of the `start` command (which doesn't natively provide any useful output data).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for something like,

```
start "window title" "C:\Program Files\app.exe > out.txt"
```

The redirection is inside the quotes, else it would fetch the output of the `start` command itself (that output is empty).